# Writing a number in textview and sending it as a string

Tags: android

I want to write a value (numbers) in a textview and sending it as a string with pressing a button. Is there any basic code of how i can do that ?. My phone must communicate with a bluetooth CC2540 kit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the bluetooth chat application in the Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Putting ints into a `TextView`:

```
textView.setText("" + intValue);
```

to get the string from a `TextView`:

```
textView.getText().toString();
```

Then you need to be more specific on how you want to send it and put up what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The user must write the power consumption value in the textbox in my project, so all random numbers can be written on it. I just want to send that written value as a string when pressing a button through bluetooth communication.